# Apollo graphql IOS Apollo.JSONDecodingError.couldNotConvert not accept geojson type

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo, apollo-ios

Hello our swift project service layer changing to graphql.

I have a problem with one service i couldn't fix it.

when i request that service with postman i get this response.

```
"geometry": {
                                    "type": "Polygon",
                                    "coordinates": [
                                        [
                                            [
                                                29.092753373269037,
                                                40.97811809220759
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.092611488452736,
                                                40.977242038407525
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.092246823722665,
                                                40.97640379460209
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.091673399985105,
                                                40.97563557185548
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.09091325797067,
                                                40.974966889541854
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.08999561055531,
                                                40.97442344138834
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.08895571996731,
                                                40.974026108590806
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.08783354305235,
                                                40.97379015785
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.086672196601718,
                                                40.97372465507278
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.085516301591124,
                                                40.973832117209916
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.08441026977872,
                                                40.97410841557424
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.083396598300855,
                                                40.97454293434828
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.0825142376034,
                                                40.97511897821329
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.081797095264825,
                                                40.975814413485494
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.081272733106807,
                                                40.976602518189814
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.080961307637363,
                                                40.9774530084815
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.080874794600845,
                                                40.97833320204484
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.08101652756386,
                                                40.97920927382032
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.081381068450455,
                                                40.980047555838965
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.081954415208383,
                                                40.98081583121897
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.0827145388265,
                                                40.98148457257322
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.08363222922952,
                                                40.98202807718617
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.084672217644673,
                                                40.98242545526654
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.085794532332987,
                                                40.982661433219654
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.086956035528427,
                                                40.98272694099583
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.088112082392307,
                                                40.982619460883285
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.089218238048193,
                                                40.98234312430574
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.090231986505675,
                                                40.981908552898325
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.09111436559944,
                                                40.9813324499927
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.091831464950364,
                                                40.98063695826104
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.092355729281223,
                                                40.979848808273886
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.09266701697732,
                                                40.978998290769894
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                29.092753373269037,
                                                40.97811809220759
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                }
```

in android it didn't give me any error but ios i had an error.

```
Error at path "user_expertise_areas.data.0.geom.features.0.geometry.coordinates)": couldNotConvert(value: <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x600000549d80>(
<__NSArrayI 0x7ff26bd37050>(
<__NSArrayI 0x600000111d20>(
29.09275337326904,
40.97811809220759
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x600000112020>(
29.09261148845274,
40.97724203840752
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x600000110320>(
29.09224682372266,
40.97640379460209
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x600000114680>(
29.0916733999851,
40.97563557185548
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x6000001160e0>(
29.09091325797067,
40.97496688954185
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x600000116660>(
29.08999561055531,
40.97442344138834
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x600000116b40>(
29.08895571996731,
40.97402610859081
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x600000116dc0>(
29.08783354305235,
40.97379015785
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x600000116fa0>(
29.08667219660172,
40.97372465507278
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x600000114e40>(
29.08551630159112,
40.97383211720992
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x600000119a20>(
29.08441026977872,
40.97410841557424
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x60000011bd00>(
29.08339659830085,
40.97454293434828
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x60000011bde0>(
29.0825142376034,
40.97511897821329
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x60000011bb80>(
29.08179709526483,
40.97581441348549
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x60000011b7c0>(
29.08127273310681,
40.97660251818981
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x600000119700>(
29.08096130763736,
40.9774530084815
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x600000119480>(
29.08087479460085,
40.97833320204484
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x600000119660>(
29.08101652756386,
40.97920927382032
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x6000001196e0>(
29.08138106845045,
40.98004755583896
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x60000011a7e0>(
29.08195441520838,
40.98081583121897
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x600000118000>(
29.0827145388265,
40.98148457257322
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x60000011b840>(
29.08363222922952,
40.98202807718617
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x60000011ba40>(
29.08467221764467,
40.98242545526654
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x600000118160>(
29.08579453233299,
40.98266143321965
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x6000001185a0>(
29.08695603552843,
40.98272694099583
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x6000001187e0>(
29.08811208239231,
40.98261946088329
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x600000118ee0>(
29.08921823804819,
40.98234312430574
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x600000119f60>(
29.09023198650567,
40.98190855289833
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x60000011a1e0>(
29.09111436559944,
40.9813324499927
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x60000011ab80>(
29.09183146495036,
40.98063695826104
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x60000011a6e0>(
29.09235572928122,
40.97984880827389
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x60000011ad80>(
29.09266701697732,
40.97899829076989
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x60000011bdc0>(
29.09275337326904,
40.97811809220759
)

)

)
, to: Swift.String)
```

i tried to add this run script but it doesn't work

```
SCRIPT_PATH="${PODS_ROOT}/Apollo/scripts" cd "${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}" "${SCRIPT_PATH}"/run-bundled-codegen.sh codegen:generate --target=swift --includes=./**/*.graphql --passthroughCustomScalars --localSchemaFile="schema.json" API.swift
```

how can i solve the problem can you help me ?

Comment: Full error message? In the JSON, `coordinates` value is an Array of Array  of Array? Seems to be an extra Array level. That's what's saying the error I guess, but since it's not complete...

Comment: i updated my question, in API.swift file this property has String type, i look android its property is object type :s

Comment: Might share the definition of your structure? Its properties and such? It expects indeed a String and not an Array. I'l not familiar with Appollo, more GraphQL, but with JSON and Codable, yes, and that error seems normal then.